# Neural network having output components that should be of different scales

Tags: optimization, deep-learning, neural-network

I am trying to train a neural network that maps vectors in R^3 into other vectors in R^3. However, the main issue is that the second component of these vectors is of the order of 10^-5, while the other two are of the order of 1 for every data point.

For this problem, I know this is the case. On the other hand, I wouldn't like to customize my architecture to the fact that the second component behaves differently.

In other words, my question is: how would you set up the network or the loss function so that the network output can be with values of different scales? The main issue I am encountering is that the loss value gets very small but the accuracy on the second component of the output is poor since improving on the second component gives a comparably small improvement overall on the loss value. An option could be to minimize a relative error, but this gives exploding gradients in my experience.